# Is there a possibility to get the download count from nuget.org in a shields.io badge?

Tags: github, nuget, badge, shields.io

Is there a possibility to get the download count from a custom package on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/) in a [shields.io](http://shields.io/) badge? Something like [image: NuGet] would be nice... Is there a possibility to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, i got it on my own. Was way too easy I guess...

```
[![NuGet Downloads](https://img.shields.io/nuget/dt/['Your project id here'].svg)]
(https://www.nuget.org/packages/['Your project id here']/)
```

So for example:
[image: NuGet Downloads]

Comment: Very nice! I like! 